# API timer stops when VBModal Form load - vb6

Tags: vb6

Good day,
   I created a vb6 program with auto logoff feature. I used API and it works fine, but only on mdiChild forms. Whenever forms loaded in a modal form, the timer stops. I tried to simulate my code line by line and then I found out that the code stops on "Form1.show vbmodal". What should I do to continue the timer even the form loaded as vbmodal?  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. 
   By the way, here is my code:

```
Private Declare Function GetQueueStatus Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal fuFlags As Long) As Long
'API For Inactivity Monitoring SMQ
Private Const QS_KEY = &H1
Private Const QS_MOUSEMOVE = &H2
Private Const QS_MOUSEBUTTON = &H4
Private Const QS_TIMER = &H10
Private Const QS_MOUSE = (QS_MOUSEMOVE Or QS_MOUSEBUTTON)
Private Const QS_INPUT = (QS_MOUSE Or QS_KEY)
Private Const QS_ALLEVENTS = (QS_MOUSE Or QS_KEY Or QS_TIMER)

Public Sub CheckInputIdle(ByVal TimeOut As Long)

Dim lTimer As Long

lTimer=Timer

Do While gCancelAutoLogOff = False
  DoEvents

     If GetQueueStatus(QS_INPUT) Then
        lTimer = Timer
     End If

     If Timer - lTimer >= TimeOut Then Exit Do
Loop
If gCancelAutoLogOff = False Then
     gCancelAutoLogOff = True
     MainForm.Logoff
End If   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are expecting as a modal dialog will block any code from running until it's closed.. From [Visual Basic Concepts: Modal and Modeless Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263470(v=vs.60).aspx):

> A modal dialog box must be closed (hidden or unloaded) before you can
>   continue working with the rest of the application.

and

> If a form is displayed as modal, the code following the Show method is
>   not executed until the dialog box is closed.

You're going to have to get rid of your modal form(s) in favor of another solution if you want your timer to fire.

Comment: Thanks C-Pound Guru

Comment: I think I must call again the API Timer function whenever the modal forms load.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have a 'timer'.  You have a cpu intensive loop, which will run for a set period of time, and within the loop you are making an api call.  The `DoEvents` statement does mean that the UI will be (mostly) responsive to the user while the loop is running.

When you then invoke a modal form display (via a different code path, presumably triggered by another event such as a button click), that modal form display will stop your cpu loop while the form is modally displayed.  As C-Pound Guru describes in their answer.

You should investigate using a Timer control (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231154(v=vs.60).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267243(v=vs.60).aspx).

Within the timer elapsed event you would make your queue status api call.  Placing the timer control on your main form will mean that the timer elapsed event will continue to fire even when you have displayed another form modally.

Comment: Thanks MarkL, the links are helpful.